# In JS/Node how would you avoid data conflicts when more than one person is editing the same records? Is there a pattern?

Tags: javascript, database, node.js

I know that in general people take soem approach of locking the data, or potentially using promises in some way, but I'm wondering if there are some general best practise patterns for this sort of task?

Comment: Database servers are generally responsible for preserving data integrity under concurrent usage.  Locking is most often the approach taken, but not necessarily.  But again, the database should be handling that for you.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your database. If you are using a relational database then you can use transactions. If you are using NoSQL then you typically have to deal with last write wins or roll your own unit of work pattern as many of these kinds of databases do not support transactions.

Additionally, if you want to handle doing conflict resolutions yourself then look into "Dynamo Systems" like Riak.

In the end your question isn't related to Node.js, it's about data access in general.

Comment: Can you explain how transactions would buffer against conflicts? is it based on the idea of isolation?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the isolation level of the transaction. Each level has its own tradeoffs and varies from vendor to vendor.